# Does setting a 1-bit wide bitfield to 2 mean the bitfield is set or unset?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

So I have a bitfield like so:

```
unsigned int foobar:1;
```

And then I set it using this code

```
uint32_t code = loadCode();
structure.foobar = code & 2;
```

So, if `code` is set to 2, would this mean that foobar is set to 1, 0, or undefined? The exact standard I'm using is actually C++11, not plain C.

Comment: Looks to me like that would be a zero... Think about it.  2 = 0000010.  Your bit field is one bit.  If you AND that against your binary value, that bit is still cleared.

Comment: btw, this isn't homework, this was brought up out of a code review when we realized no one on our team knows if this is a standard defined behavior or not, unsure why the downvote.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer that's my thoughts as well, but then C++ has weird semantics with boolean casting (ie, `x>0 = true`), that might apply to bitfields as well

Comment: Have you tried it in a piece of sample code?

Comment: @Earlz But your bitfield is not of type `bool`, it's of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer yes, but I'm more concerned by if it's standard-defined or not, as this is compiled by a lot of different compiler versions

Comment: @Earlz: Even if the standard would allow it: it just does not make any sense. There is no excuse for writing such code.

Comment: @Earlz It is standard-defined.

Comment: Brute force it and let the compiler optimizer sort it out. `structure.foobar = (code & 2)?1:0;`

Comment: It would be standard defined for the reason that I outlined; it's a standard arithmetic (albeit, boolean) operation resulting in an lvalue assignment. :)

Comment: @Earlz T.C.'s answer is more correct than mine is. Can you accept their answer instead so I can delete mine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[expr.ass]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#6):

> When the left operand of an assignment operator is a bit-field that
>   cannot represent the value of the expression, the resulting value of
>   the bit-field is implementation-defined.

Similarly, for [initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.8.sentence-4):

> When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent,
>   the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

This is added by [DR 1816](http://wg21.link/CWG1816). As a defect report that fixes a bug in the standard, it is de facto retroactive.

Comment: I'm not seeing this in the C++11 spec, is this from a later spec? [expr.ass]/6 in C++11 is *"When the left operand of an assignment operator denotes a reference to T, the operation assigns to the
object of type T denoted by the reference."*

Comment: Ah, so this was fixed in C++14? I'd guess then that for C++11 the answer is "it depends how you read the spec?"

Comment: @cdhowie Formally 17, it looks like, but as a DR it should reach all the way back. Also note the point made in the discussion that that [conv.integral]/1 says that the conversion is from a prvalue to a prvalue, and there are no prvalue bit-fields.